# Wordpress.com blog flexibility

Tags: wordpress, blogs, wordpress.com

I'm pretty new to web design (but a very experienced programmer) and I'm creating a pretty simple wordpress blog for a friend. Take a look if you want: http://beachief.com/. Right now he has a domain mapped to a wordpress.com account, so I have no access to plugins or custom themes. This is what he wants me to add:

A like/dislike function for all posts

One section with 2 blog columns side by side (not supported by the theme - or any others that I could find)

The ability to let users log in and post their own content

My question is: is this stuff possible to do with a wordpress.com account? Or will he need to switch to an independently hosted wordpress.org site? Let me know what you think, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He will need to switch to Wordpress.org and be independantly hosted.
Wordpress.com does not let you use plugins or custom themes, unless you pay for a VIP plan.

Comment: But can any of those things be done without plugins or custom themes? Can I add a second blog column using the CSS stylesheet editor?

Comment: No you can't. HTML is **markup language** for _laying out elements and content_ and CSS is a **stylesheet** for **styling element's presentation**. HTML's purpose is to hold the content of the elements of the page, and CSS's purpose is to define its presentational values. CSS helps to seperate the presentation from the content. 

For that reason, you cannot create a new sidebar by editing the CSS. You would have to edit the HTML for that, as that's where the elements of the page and their content are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I really like Wordpress. It's an incredibly flexible, stable, and strong CMS.

If you're really wanting the like/dislike functions, I found this:
http://www.mrphpguru.com/blog/2011/01/14/like-dislike-post-plugins-for-wordpress/

But there are also some other great post rating alternatives here:
http://www.geeksucks.com/showcases/10-cool-wordpress-plugins-for-ratings.htm

and for people logging in and posting their own content, you can manage users through the Wordpress backend (usually yoursite.com/wp-login or yoursite.com/wp-admin), and allow or deny specific permissions from them.

Comment: Ya those are good links, I was more wondering though if I could get that functionality without using plugins

Comment: Ah. I'm sure it's possible, it just may take longer. If it's just that you don't want to use plugins, you could theoretically copy the plugin code into wordpress documents, and then implement the PHP in your display, but then again, you'd probably be violating the plugin license, or something like that, so you didn't hear it from me.

Comment: Haha true.. I'm not sure if I can even get into the wordpress documents though. The only place I see where I can directly change code is in the CSS stylesheet editor. Can I code the things I need in that CSS editor? or is there another place where I can gain access?